# How do I measure sound pressure using the iPhone internal microphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I want to measure the loudness of ambient sound. Having read a number of posts on stackoverflow I feel more confused than I was originally. Im not a sound engineer just a programmer.

I think I need to calculate dBSPL with the formula 20 * log10 (voltage / Voltage_Ref)

So for this I need to sample the internal microphone voltage (or pressure in Pascals?) level. The class AVAudioRecorder allows me to meter read the peakPowerForChannel but this gives a dbFS reading between 160 and 0. Where 0 is full power. How do I access the voltage/pressure levels, with another API perhaps?

I had read that roughly 0 dbFS = 99 db SPL. But that would mean the maximum db SPL I could read using the peakPowerForChannel reading would be 99 db SPL. I'm looking to read levels higher than this.

Any information on this would be most appreciated - im somewhat stuck at this point.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to test your particular iOS device model (and perhaps production batch) against a known sound source at a given distance and relationship to the mic in an anechoic chamber.  The voltage and pressure relationship is neither specified by Apple nor available from any API.

Comment: Also, note that the iPhone's response curve is probably not flat. You'd have to test at a variety of different frequencies as well.